# Is there test inheritance in VisualStudio?

Tags: automated-testing, visualstudio, test-strategy

Imagine you have a sequence of web tests in `Visual Studio`, recorded individually i.e., `Login`, `Event A` and `Event B`.

To do both `Event A` and `Event B` you need to login. Is there a way for tests `Event A` and `Event B` to inherit `Login` test?

I'm calling it `inheritance`, but don't know if that is the correct term please correct me if I'm wrong.

This way my tests can be almost modular.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is yes.  You can right click on the test case in the web test editor and select "Add call to web test" and it will call that web test.  Any context parameters that are required by your "Login" test can be set in the other test or in the load test and will be used by Login when executed.